# how to create a password that prevents the user from discovering the password and changing it in desktop applications gui

Tags: java, desktop-application

i want to make an application to manage passwords, where in this application you will have a main password that will access the application that will show the registered passwords. How do I prevent this password from being discovered or changed by the user. This master password is used to access the system.
I am using the hsqldb bank to store the passwords that will be registered by the user.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "discovering the password and changing it in desktop applications gui"

Comment: @Lino, I have a desktop application, that to enter it there is a screen to fill a password, but the user can go to the directory and change the password manually in the application files and I don't want him to do that, understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must not ever** store **any** of those passwords (master or registered) in clear text anywhere. Otherwise you can just put the passwords in your favourite text editor of choice and save it as plain text file, no difference.

You need to use the master password (to create a key) to encrypt and decrypt all other passwords / data and only store the encrypted result somewhere. You never store the master password anywhere, ever!

After that there is no place to change a password because the password is nowhere to be found. The only way to change the master password is to 1. enter both old and new password 2. use the old password to decrypt 3. use the new password to encrypt 4. store the result.

If you forget the master password all data is gone (as it should be) because there is no difference between you loosing your password and an attacker not having it in the first place.